# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000] (Android Studio)

Tags: php, android, android-studio, android-volley, volley

estoy tratando de hacer manipulación de datos, tengo mi aplicación en Heroku y quiero consumir la API desde una aplicación móvil:
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

La el código que adjunto es de la aplicación hecha en PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
  require_once("../config/Conection.php");
  require_once("../models/Alumno.php");
      $alumno = new Alumno();
      $body = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
            
      switch($_GET["op"]){
          case "GetAll":
              $data = $alumno -> get_alumnos();
              echo json_encode ($data);
              break;
          case "GetAlumno":
                $data = $alumno -> get_alumno($body["Matricula"]);
                echo json_encode ($data);
              break;
          case "InsertAlumno":
                $data = $alumno -> save_alumno($body["Nombre"],$body["Apellidos"],$body["Matricula"],$body["Fecha_Nac"],$body["Telefono"],$body["Correo"],$body["Direccion"],$body["Sexo"]);
                echo "insersion Correcta";
              break;
          case "DeleteAlumno":
                $data = $alumno -> delete_alumno($body["Matricula"]);
                echo "Borrado Correcta";
              break;
      }
```

Y Aquí los métodos para manipular los datos

```
<?php

class Alumno extends Conection{
    public function get_alumnos(){
        $coneccion = parent::conexion();
        $sql = $coneccion-> prepare("SELECT * FROM alumno");
        $sql -> execute();
    return $resultado = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}
    public function get_alumno($mat){
        $coneccion = parent::conexion();
        $sql = $coneccion-> prepare("SELECT * FROM alumno WHERE Matricula = ?");
        $sql->bindValue(1,$mat);
        $sql -> execute();
    return $resultado = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}
    public function delete_alumno($mat){
        $coneccion = parent::conexion();
        $sql = $coneccion-> prepare("DELETE FROM alumno WHERE Matricula = ?");
        $sql->bindValue(1,$mat);
        $sql -> execute();
    return $resultado = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}
    public function save_alumno($nombre,$apellidos,$matricula,$fecha_Nac,$telefono,$correo,$direccion,$sexo){
        $coneccion = parent::conexion();
        $sql = $coneccion-> prepare("INSERT INTO alumno (idAlumno,Nombre,Apellidos,Matricula,Fecha_Nac,Telefono,Correo,Direccion,Sexo)VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $sql->bindValue(1,$nombre);
        $sql->bindValue(2,$apellidos);
        $sql->bindValue(3,$matricula);
        $sql->bindValue(4,$fecha_Nac);
        $sql->bindValue(5,$telefono);
        $sql->bindValue(6,$correo);
        $sql->bindValue(7,$direccion);
        $sql->bindValue(8,$sexo);
        $sql -> execute();
    return $resultado = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }
}
```

Con Android estoy usando Volley puedo consultar todos los datos, pero al momento de insertar datos no puedo agregar data porque en el CLI de heroku me aparece eso:

```
2022-06-07T19:59:01.682083+00:00 app[web.1]: [07-Jun-2022 19:59:01 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'Nombre' cannot be null in /app/models/Alumno.php:38
```

Y capturando todos los datos, en la interfaz de la aplicación estoy recuperando todo, el problema creo que está en la petición

```
private void crearAlumno(final String name, final String apellido, final String mat,final String fechaNac,final String tel,final String email,final String direc,final String genero) {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                URLCrear,
                new Response.Listener<String>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                    }
                }
               , new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        System.out.println(name+mat+apellido+fechaNac+email+direc+tel+genero);

                        System.out.println(error);
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Nombre",name);
                params.put("Apellido",apellido);
                params.put("Matricula",mat);
                params.put("Fecha_Nac",fechaNac);
                params.put("Telefono",tel);
                params.put("Correo",email);
                params.put("Direccion",direc);
                params.put("Sexo",genero);
                System.out.println(params);

                return params;
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Y aquí está el error de la consola de Android Studio

```
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: Using Network Security Config from 
resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
I/System.out: {Nombre=alex, Correo=ctgr@.com, 
Telefono=777123456789, Matricula=1234567890, Apellido=marin, 
Direccion=gthy, Sexo=F, Fecha_Nac=01011990}
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
E/Volley: [483031] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: 
Unexpected response code 500 for https://androidoptativa.herokuapp.com/controller/alumnosController.php?op=InsertAlumno
```

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El principal problema se indica aquí:

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
> violation: 1048 Column 'Nombre' cannot be null in
> /app/models/Alumno.php:38

Al realiza tu petición, cuando intentas insertar un registro,

```
 $data = $alumno -> save_alumno($body["Nombre"],$body["Apellidos"],$body["Matricula"],$body["Fecha_Nac"],$body["Telefono"],$body["Correo"],$body["Direccion"],$body["Sexo"]);
```

**no estás enviando un valor correcto para `Nombre`, este valor se está enviando con valor `null`** y en tu tabla no se permite un valor `null` para el campo `Nombre`.

Comment: Así mismo tengo con otros métodos pero no funciona, funciona con un parámetro pero no se puede